# What is the best way to check for element is present if i have many to check using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have around 40-50 elements to check in a page using Selenium WebDriver and I am using the code below to check each element. Can someone please tell me what is the best way to do such testing if I have many elements in one page. Boolean. What I am doing now is:

```
isPresentquote_graph_displayed = driver.findElements(element1).size() > 0; 
isPresentquote_graph_displayed = driver.findElements(element2).size() > 0; 
isPresentquote_graph_displayed = driver.findElements(element3).size() > 0; 
isPresentquote_graph_displayed = driver.findElements(element4).size() > 0;
```

Like this I am writing each of the 40 to 50 elements and checking if the boolean value is true or false. I was wondering if there is any better way to do this?

Comment: I would create an array with all the elements, then loop through them.  This is also assuming you want to check the same value for all.  If you wanted to check true for some and false for others, you'd want to assign the element and value in the array, then you can pass both into the check.

Comment: yea that make sense. thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Sad status of questions being asked here: using a loop to perform an action repeatedly is a good suggestion. Why it was not obvious for OP? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an array with all the elements, then loop through them. This is also assuming you want to check the same value for all. If you wanted to check true for some and false for others, you'd want to assign the element and value in the array, then you can pass both into the check.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create the list and iterate through the each and every element in the list and find that if it is present

```
list[] ele = new list[](driver.findElement(""));
foreach(var elementpresent in ele)
{
    if(elementpresent.isPresent) //or elementpresent.isDisplayed
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0:
    }
}
```

I hope this works